# .NET MVC 5 OData Custom Action Bound to Entity with Version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata

In .NET MVC 4/5, I can create a custom action bound to an entity. e.g.

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
...
var testAction = builder.EntityType<MyEntity>().Action("Test");
testAction.Returns<bool>();
testAction.Parameter<int>("testParameter");
...
return builder.GetEdmModel()
```

But how do I implement a versioned custom action bound to an entity using VersionedODataModelBuilder? e.g.

```
var builder = new VersionedODataModelBuilder(config)
{
    ModelConfigurations =
    {
        new TestModelConfiguration()
    }
    ...
    // BAD: property EntityType does not exist on the builder object.
    var testAction = builder.EntityType<MyEntity>().Action("Test"); 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully create a custom action and custom function on a route with the following approach.

I needed to add my problem code into TestModelConfiguration.cs which makes the ODataModelBuilder object available.

web.config:

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

TestModelConfiguration.cs:

```
private EntityTypeConfiguration<RunViewModel> ConfigureCurrent(ODataModelBuilder builder)
{
    var pingFunction = builder.EntityType<RunViewModel>().Function("Ping");
    pingFunction.Returns<bool>();
    pingFunction.Parameter<int>("test");
    pingFunction.Namespace = "Function";

    var pongAction = builder.EntityType<RunViewModel>().Action("Pong");
    pongAction.Returns<bool>();
    pongAction.Parameter<int>("test");
    pongAction.Namespace = "Action";
```

TestController.cs:

```
public class RunController : BaseODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("Test({key})/Function.Ping(test={test})")]
    public bool Ping([FromODataUri] int key, int test)
    {
        return true;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute("Test({key})/Action.Pong")]
    public IHttpActionResult Pong([FromODataUri] int key, ODataActionParameters parameters)
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }
```